# Git - how to create branch equal to fork base

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have fork of one of the repos. I have got there edited `master` branch. I want to create new branch in my repostitory, which will be equal to `master` in orginal repo (this repo I created fork of). How can I do that? `git branch newbraaanch origin/master` gives be branch equal to `master`, but in my fork....

That is important. I have to finish my C++ project...

Comment: You should remove the c++ tag as your question is not specific or related to c++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the original repo as a remote:

```
git remote add foobar https://github.com/foo/bar
```

Then do a fetch:

```
git fetch foobar
```

Finally, branch:

```
git branch newbraaanch foobar/master
```